# Divisibility of repdigits - Prove that 99 divides even copies of 9 only

Tags: divisibility

Let A(n) be a repdigit containing n copies of 9. E.g. A(2) = 99.

Prove that n must be even for A(2) to divide A(n).

As such, if Bn is n copies of x. For what values of n will B(2) divide B(n)?

---

I have solved the problem by showing that 11|A(n) for even n (and clearly 9|A(n) for all n). However, I would like an alternative solution, as well as to generalise the solution for other repdigits.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Simply specialize the linked divisibility results from polynomials to integers (put $x=10$ there).

Answer (score 0):

$A(1) = 9$, $A(2) = 9*10+9 = 99$, $A(3) = 9*10^2+9*10+9 = 999$

Therefore 
$A(n) = 9*10^{n-1} + A(n-1)$

$A(n) = 10^n-1$

Say $n=2*m$

$A(2*m) = 10^{2*m}-1$

Now factor it
$A(2*m) = (10^m+1)*(10^m-1)$

But $A(m) = 10^m-1$

$A(2*m) = (10^m+1)*A(m)$

Therefore $n$ must be a multiple of $2$ for $A(2)$ to divide $A(n)$, $n$ is just just even but a multiple of $2$

Comment: How do the 2nd last line lead to the conclusion?

Comment: After seeing that $A(2*m) = (10^m+1)*A(m)$ then $\frac{A(2*m)}{A(m)} = 10^m+1$, if $m=2$ then $A(4)$ is a multiple of $A(2)$, if $m$ was $4$, then $A(8)$ is a multiple of $A(4)$, therefore it is a multiple of $A(2)$ also, so this process continues until we final see that if $m$ is a multiple of $2$, then $A(m)$ is a multiple of $A(2)$